# java Spring boot get the file name in the controller when post request is sent via curl

Tags: java, spring, web-services, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am trying to upload a file from client to server the client uploads the file to the server using the curl command

**client command:**

```
curl -X POST -T pom.xml http://localhost:8070/put --header "origmd5":"7AB4E6F0A4A2D3CBB200DB1677D99AD75"
```

Now in the controller i.e at the server side the code is as follows

**server side:**

```
@PostMapping(value="readFile")
public ResponseEntity<?> uploadfile(@RequestBody String filecontent) throws IllegalStateException, IOException {
System.out.println(filecontent);//prints the content which is inside the file uploaded by client
  return null;
  }
```

1.Now the problem statement is how do we get the file name that has been sent by the client the contents of the file can be parsed in the request body but how to get the file name?

```
 @RequestBody String filecontent
```

2.i am using string like above to parse request body (i.e content of file is stored in String) is this the correct way storing contents of file in string?

Comment: If the file is the body of the request you cannot. You will have to add an additional parameter to the request.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You actually need [MultipartFile](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/multipart/MultipartFile.html) which will give you all the information related to the uploaded file.

```
uploadfile(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file){
String fileName = file.getOriginalFilename()
}
```

Comment: thanks!. i know it works by specifying the request parameter  but i want to upload without specifying the file parameter at client side

Comment: I am not sure if this is possible. You have to give some name to your uploaded data so that SpringBoot can bind it at Controller layer. BTW why this strange requirement?

Comment: @saitejapakalapati One way or another, you have to upload the file info to the back end to let it know the name

Comment: @saitejapakalapati You cant upload file just by it fileName. You have to have multipartFile

Answer (score -3):

Using Multipart might be a better solution when uploading files:

```
@PostMapping(value="readFile")
public ResponseEntity<?> uploadfile(@RequestParam(value="file") MultipartFile fileContent){
```

}